# Flutter - Image to File Conversion Issues

Tags: flutter, image, dart, tensorflow-lite

**Question in Short:**

How to convert the Image data to File, which will be used on tflite classification. Using https://pub.dev/packages/image library

**Details:**

I'm dealing with a flutter app, where image is picked from gallery, cropped and sent to the classifier. What i need is adding some white spaces to sides of cropped image (depending on its size), so that scale of the image not change when fed into the classifier. Where scale information is quite critical for the dataset.

for example:

Let's say we picked the cheetah image and cropped from the marked position

[image: original]

Then we obtain this:

[image: cropped]

If the cropped image is scaled to 224x224, then all the precious scale data is gone:

[image: skeweed]

Aim is creating/forming an image like this (where black borders put intentionally), and feed to the algorithm:

[image: proper]

Using some fill and copyInto functions, inside the addWhiteFillersToImage(), and creating the IMG.Image bigImage. But unable to convert bigImage to _selectedFile. Have issues here.

Adding the code below. Please note that, I'm a beginner in flutter, and if you have any other alternative approach in mind, all wellcomed.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_cropper/image_cropper.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:tflite/tflite.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as IMG;


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget { ... }

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  File? _selectedFile;
  bool _inProcess = false;
  List? _outputs;

  void initState() { ... }

  loadModel() async { ... }

  Widget getImageWidget() { ... }

  addWhiteFillersToImage(File? filly) async{
    if(filly !=null) {
      //https://github.com/brendan-duncan/image/wiki/Examples
      IMG.Image? image = IMG.decodeJpg(filly.readAsBytesSync());
      int whiteW = 0;
      int whiteH = 0;
      IMG.Image? bigImage;
      if (image != null)
      {
        if (image.height > image.width) {
          whiteW = (image.height - image.width) ~/ 2;
          whiteH = (image.height).toInt();
          bigImage = IMG.Image(whiteH, whiteH); //empty white square image
          IMG.fill(bigImage, IMG.getColor(255, 255, 255));
          IMG.copyInto(bigImage, image, dstX: whiteW, blend: false);
        } else if (image.width > image.height) {
          whiteW = (image.width).toInt();
          whiteH = (image.width - image.height) ~/ 2;
          bigImage = IMG.Image(whiteW, whiteW);
          IMG.copyInto(bigImage, image, dstY: whiteH, blend: false);
        } else {
          bigImage = image;
        }

        // ?? Can't convert bigImage to File type, i mean to _selectedFile
        // ?? File(_selectedFile!.path).writeAsBytesSync(IMG.encodeJpg(bigImage));
        // ??

        setState(() {

        });
      }
    }
  }

  getImage(ImageSource source) async {
    setState((){_inProcess = true;});

    XFile? imagy = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: source);
    if(imagy != null)
    {
      File? croppy = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
          sourcePath: imagy.path,
          //aspectRatio: CropAspectRatio(ratioX: null, ratioY: 1),
          compressQuality: 100,
          maxWidth: 700,
          maxHeight: 700,
          compressFormat: ImageCompressFormat.jpg,
          androidUiSettings: AndroidUiSettings(
            toolbarColor: Colors.deepOrange,
            toolbarTitle: "RPS Cropper",
            statusBarColor: Colors.deepOrange.shade900,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          )
      );
      if(croppy !=null)
        {
          addWhiteFillersToImage(croppy);
          setState(()
          {
            classifyImage(_selectedFile!);
          });
        }
    }
  }

  // Classifiy the image selected
  classifyImage(File image) async { //
    var output = await Tflite.runModelOnImage(
      path: image.path,
      numResults: 10,
      threshold: 0.01,
      imageMean: 1,
      imageStd: 1,
      asynch: true,

    );
    setState(() {
      _inProcess = false;
      _outputs = output!;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { ... }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? `writeAsBytesSync(IMG.encodeJpg(bigImage))` seems the right way to go. Do you need to create a temporary filename first? If so, look at `path_provider`.

Comment: thank you Richard Heap. that path_provider library solved my issue after some trial and errors. i can mark it as answer if you like

Comment: Feel free to add your own answer based on what you ended up with.